# Heap Sort. What's wrong in this code?

Tags: java, heapsort

I am able to create a Max Heap using a function heapify() but when i try to call it again(to delete max and create a sorted array) the program gets stuck/doesn't stop taking input. What's wrong?

Is this a memory problem?If I increase the number of calls by increasing the frequency of for loop it still works fine.

```
public class HeapSort 
{
int[] heap;
public void sort(int length)
{
    int temp;
    for(int i=length;i>=1;i--)
    {
        heapify(i,length);
    }
    //if I try to call heapify again(even once) after this,the program gets stuck
}
public void heapify(int i,int l)
{
    int lchild=2*i,rchild,max;
    int temp;
    while(lchild<=l)
    {

            rchild=(2*i)+1;
        if(rchild<=l)
            max=(heap[lchild]>heap[rchild])? lchild:rchild;
        else
            max=lchild;
        if(heap[i]<heap[max])
        {
            temp=heap[i];
            heap[i]=heap[max];
            heap[max]=temp;
            i=max;
        }
        lchild=2*i;
    }

}
public static void main(String args[]) throws  IOException
{
    BufferedReader r= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int length=Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
    HeapSort Heap=new HeapSort();
    Heap.heap=new int[length+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=length;i++)
    Heap.heap[i]=Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
    Heap.sort(length);
    for(int i=1;i<=length;i++)
        System.out.print(Heap.heap[i]+" ");
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a while loop in the `heapify()` method? You just have to check your children, pick the largest one between yourself (the node) and your children, swap, and recurse.

Comment: I don't know what you've implemented there, but this is definitely not how a heap works.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I have rechecked and I am able to make a MaxHeap implementing this method.The idea is to take a node and swap it with it's larger children if it is smaller than it's children.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena Recursion is replaced by while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Heapify should be done for length/2 iterations because it is like a tree structure. 
Here is a complete code for heap sort...This sort array 's'

```
public class HeapSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s[]={"aaaa","dddd","cccc","gggg","bbbbb"};
    AsHeap(s);
    HeapSort(s);
    for(String x:s){
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
public static void AsHeap(String s[]){
    for( int i = s.length / 2; i >= 0; i-- ){
        DownHeap( s, i, s.length );
    }
}
public static void HeapSort(String[] s){
    for(int i=s.length-1;i>0;i--){
        swap(s,0,i);
        DownHeap(s,0,i);
    }
}
public static int getLeftChildIndex(int i){

    return 2 * i + 1;
}
private static void DownHeap(String[] s, int i, int length) {
    int indexOfChild;
    String temp;
    for(temp=s[i];getLeftChildIndex(i)<length;i=indexOfChild){
        indexOfChild=getLeftChildIndex(i);
        if(indexOfChild !=length-1 && s[indexOfChild].compareTo(s[indexOfChild+1])<0){
            indexOfChild++;
        }
        if(temp.compareTo(s[indexOfChild])<0){
            s[i] = s[indexOfChild];
        } else{
            break;
        }
    }
    s[i] = temp;

}
public static void swap(String s[],int x,int y){
    String temp=s[x];
    s[x]=s[y];
    s[y]=temp;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The while loop isn't terminating when there is no swap between the  parent and the child(i.e. the parent is greater than the child).
The value of i(just above main method) doesn't change when parent is greater. Simply taking the line i=max outside the if block [if(heap[i]

Also,is there any sequence to learn Algorithms?If so,kindly guide me.

Thank you.